# Anime about a girl with short red hair who was some type of fighter and fought demons

Tags: story-identification, anime, demons

I am trying to find the name of an anime where there was this girl with short red hair who was some type of fighter and fought demons.

It was an ecchi anime, so there was some tentacle scenes.

There was also this time that one of the girl's friends got taken over by a dark force or demon at an amusement park.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made? Also, how did the girl fight the demons? (With her bare hands? Weapons? Magic?) Did she wear a special costume or just regular clothes? And did she go to school or have a job?

Comment: One of these, perhaps? - https://gaminggorilla.com/best-red-haired-anime-girls/

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.